# 'System.AccessViolationException' in WPF; DLLImport and unsigned char*

Tags: c#, c++, c, wpf, dllimport

I am trying to import a DLL written in C. The definition of the function is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) double GetData(unsigned char *Buffer, int l)
{
    int i;
    for (i= 0; i<l; i++)
    {
        Buffer[i] = MyVal[i];  //MyVal is a global Variable, updated by differnt process
    }
    return 3.14;
}
```

The counter function used in C# to import this DLL is:

```
[DllImportAttribute(DLLLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern double GetData(StringBuilder buffer, int l);
```

which is called using,

```
int l = 8;
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(8) ;
double t = GetData(buffer, l);
string S = buffer.ToString()
```

But when I run thiscode, I get an error,

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in
TestCode.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is 
often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

PS: There are two processes that are using the same DLL. `MyVal` is getting updated by one process and the other process (`WPF`) is trying to get that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `StringBuilder` maps to `char*`. `byte[]` maps to `unsigned char*`. If you use `StringBuilder` then the caller should null terminate the string. But this doesn't look like text data at all. Your error is probably just that `MyVal` has not been initialised correctly. Where is the [mcve]? And why don't you do some debugging?

Comment: Having two distinct processes use the same DLL and getting them to share *data* is a very untrivial programming technique.  It requires #pragma section or a memory-mapped file.  Such a vehicle *always* requires some kind of synchronization to ensure that the data is valid and not actively being written.  Very important details, nothing like that is visible in the snippet.  So is likely missing, random failure is expected when MyVal was never initialized.  If you don't yet know how to debug native code that is called by [DllImport] then pursue that instead.